# Error SQL0: The reference to external elements from the source named 'master.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded

Tags: sql-server, sqlpackage

Despite the fact that:

a) my master.dacpac file exists in the same directory as the dacpac I'm attempting to publish

b) I've also copied the master.dacpac to the current working directory

c) I've added the master database as database reference with suppress unresolved reference errors tick box checked

despite this I am still getting:

Error SQL0: The reference to external elements from the source named 'master.dacpac' could not be resolved, because no such source is loaded.

Can someone please advise me as to what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: Isn't this the same thing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103775/hosted-vs2017-agent-build-master-dacpac-does-not-exist

Comment: It might well be

Comment: Tried the advice in that thread, can't get anything to resolve my issue, I'm wondering if I'm hitting a nuance / bug of using sqlpackage on Linux.