# Azure Build Sql Dacpac not found

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task, dacpac

so we are trying to build an MS SQL database pipeline. the issue that I'm running into is due to dacpac not found. They are in our repo
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2YPC.png)

now I did notice that the build is looking at an enterprise pathway. my local build and my push to the repo was from a professional VS version.  How can this be resolved? Every DB reference is having the same issue in my solution.  my sln files are being recognized just not my Database references.

Comment: What does your azure-pipelines.yml look like? 
Also in the error message the path looks like its pointing to a Debug build? Are you not maybe doing a Release build?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message, the reference to the master.dacpac is incorrect. Please open and check your .sqlproj file. You will find the reference to the Master database like this:

```
<ArtifactReference Include="$(DacPacRootPath)\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\130\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac">
  <HintPath>$(DacPacRootPath)\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\130\SqlSchemas\master.dacpac</HintPath>
```

If your `Include="` is a hard coded path, you can try to copy the contents of the HintPath element to the Include attribute.
Please refer to [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45103775/hosted-vs2017-agent-build-master-dacpac-does-not-exist) for more details.

Comment: I did follow your steps and I'm still getting the same error message. I even recreated my pipeline and still the issues.

 <ArtifactReference Include="$(DacPacRootPath)\bin\Debug\master.dacpac">
      <HintPath>$(DacPacRootPath)\bin\Debug\master.dacpac</HintPath>
      <SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>True</SuppressMissingDependenciesErrors>
      <DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>master</DatabaseVariableLiteralValue>
    </ArtifactReference>

Comment: @Tdubs Can you share the configuration of your pipeline?